# Why would I want to install a package while ignoring dependencies?

Tags: python, pip

Like the title states, why would I want to install a package while ignoring dependencies using the `--no-deps` switch? Seems to me doing so could cause some packages to malfunction.

Surprisingly, I cannot find the answer to this.

Comment: What if you manually installed a dependency and pip just doesn't know about it ? An override option is always a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues are caused by conflicting dependencies. In those cases, you might install the problematic dependency yourself instead of letting pip autofetch it.

Answer (score 1):

It also might be the case that some dependencies are for features of the package that you don't require, like a graphical display library as an example.

If you wish to use the software for some other purpose, and will never need these features, then skipping the dependencies may save time or at least the headache of installing possibly complex libraries/dependencies.